# Overlay with blur effect

Tags: android

I am new to android development and want to know if there is a way to make an overlay with some views and then put a blur effect on everything behind which I can make invisible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is use a library. Take a look at this one: https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

With the library you only need to do this:

```
Blurry.with(context)
  .radius(10)
  .sampling(8)
  .color(Color.argb(66, 255, 255, 0))
  .async()
  .onto(rootView);
```

> To add dependency just add `compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'` to
>   your app level `build.gradle` and sync it. Then you will able to use
>   above code in your module.

Comment: thank you... First I will learn to add libraries and than I will use it

Comment: It is not typical, Edited answer for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it